# Bloqueando um diretório para todo mundo menos o servidor local

Tags: htaccess

Galera uso o plugin Autocomplete do JQuery, e dentro da pasta do meu servidor, eu tenho uma pasta chamada Busca, com vários arquivos php. Queria saber como bloquear esta pasta, para que apenas o meu servidor tenha acesso a ela.

Tentei fazer via .htacess, porém não esta dando certo, Veja como eu fiz:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 11.12.4.41  # Aqui eu coloquei o ip locar do meu servidor
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?